# Errors keeps coming up whenever I try pip installing anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

[image: The mentioned errors I get while trying pip install]

```
Error checking for conflicts.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\digaa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2584, in version
    return self._version
  File "c:\users\digaa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2691, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
  AttributeError: _version

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\users\digaa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 503, in _warn_about_conflicts
    package_set, _dep_info = check_install_conflicts(to_install)
   File "c:\users\digaa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 108, in check_install_conflicts
    package_set, _ = create_package_set_from_installed()
   File "c:\users\digaa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\check.py", line 47, in create_package_set_from_installed
    package_set[name] = PackageDetails(dist.version, dist.requires())
   File "c:\users\digaa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2589, in version
    raise ValueError(tmpl % self.PKG_INFO, self)
ValueError: ("Missing 'Version:' header and/or METADATA file", Unknown [unknown version] (c:\users\digaa\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+_version

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your pip version using below command on windows

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: It's the latest 19.0.3